# Background subtraction when background brightness is unknown

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image

I'm currently working on a computer vision project, and got most of my algorithm working. However I'm currently doing background subtraction manually on every image. This is because the most common background subtraction algorithms that I can find make use of thresholding, and my project should deal with backgrounds both brighter and darker than the object I want to extract.

This is the way I am subtracting the background currently (using python and the scikit stack):

```
val = filters.threshold_otsu(image)
return image > val
```

Of course, this only works with backgrounds darker than the subject.
I had the idea of finding whether or not the background is bright, and then depending on that change the sign of the inequality, but could not find a way to do that.

Is there a background subtraction algorithm which is able to handle both bright and dark backgrounds, or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no fixed method of solving your problem generally. Foreground and background can be defined differently according to situations.

That being said, it is not impossible to use some heuristic method to make the algorithm work on your dataset. It will be helpful if you can share some of the images to give us a better understanding of your definition of foreground and background.

Here are some of heuristic method that might help:

1. Run Ostu thresholding with both THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV. Then assuming your foreground is always centered, choose the result where the a large portion of the center region is white.
2. If the foreground is always larger than backgorund or vice versa, calculate the area of white region instead.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I think the second method might generally work in my case, I will try and get back to you. My dataset consists of images of hands with normally a simple background. I will try this!

Comment: I've implemented the second method,and it works great with my current datasets! Marked as answer

Answer (score -1):

There are several automatic thresholding techiques available. One of them is Otsu.

http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html

It is implemented in opencv (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('noisy2.png',0)
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Comment: Yes, however otsu with cv2.THRESH_BINARY assumes the background is darker than the foreground, and the inverse for cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV. I am searching for a way to threshold without knowing if the background is darker or brighter than the foreground.